# How can I change command and option about 'date' command in bash?

Tags: bash, date, awk, timestamp

### I want to convert this bash command to shell script.

`BASH`

Input:

```
date --date="Wed Aug 25 22:37:44 +0900 2021" +"%s"
```

Output:

```
1629898664
```

---

`SHELL`

tmp.sh:

```
function time(a, b, c, d, e) { return date --date="a b c d +0900 e" +"%s" }
{print time($1, $2, $3, $4, $5}
```

timeline:

```
Wed Aug 25 22:37:44 2021
```

Command:

```
awk -f tmp.sh timeline
```

Output:

```
awk: tmp.sh:1: function cvtTime(w) { return date --date="Thu May 14 23:40:52 +0900 2020" +"%s" }
awk: tmp.sh:1:                                         ^ syntax error
```

- 

What about timeline file has multiple lines? Like:

```
Wed Aug 25 22:37:44 2021 JACK
Wed Aug 26 22:37:44 2021 EMILY
Wed Aug 27 22:37:44 2021 SAM
```

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
date --date="${1} ${2} ${3} ${4} +0900 ${5}" +"%s"
done
```

Want:

```
1629898664 JACK
1629985064 EMILY
1630071464 SAM
```

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: Do you know what `awk` does?

Comment: Shell functions don't have named parameters.

Comment: You seem to be confusing shell scripts and awk scripts.

Comment: Also, you're missing the `)` at the end of the call of `time`

Comment: I got that. It sovled!!!

Comment: Given the provided arguments , it could be done as `TZ='UTC-9' date --date="$@" '+%s'` in the script and calling it as `./tmp.sh "Wed Aug 25 22:37:44 2021"`

Comment: Can I ask about how it goes when timeline file has multiple lines? Like 'Wed Aug 25 22:37:44 2021 \n Wed Aug 25 22:37:44 2021 \n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want a shell script that is invoked with five command line parameters:

1. A weekday (in a three-letter format)
2. A month (in a three-letter format)
3. Day-of-month
4. A time expression (HH:MM:SS)
5. A year (four digits)

(Note that 1. is redundant, it is implied by 2., 3., and 5.)

Hence a somewhat minimal shell script would look sth. like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

date --date="${1} ${2} ${3} ${4} +0900 ${5}" +"%s"
```

Of course, this can be greatly improved, e.g., by adding sanity checks for the passed parameters.

In case you want to store the date information in a file so that you can pass a single `filename` parameter to the script instead (allowing for multiple such lines), the following variation will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a i; do
    echo $(date --date="${i[0]} ${i[1]} ${i[2]} ${i[3]} +0900 ${i[4]}" +"%s") ${i[5]}
done < ${1}
```

Note, however, that this version expects an additional *name* parameter after the date information in each line.

In any event, no need for `awk` here.